# Python split without deleting the delimiter

Tags: python, split

I know that this question will be maybe marked as a duplicate, but I already read the other ones and they didn´t help me.

I have files that looks like this. I want to delete every character before the 
`<?xml`

The example text.

```
21.12.2017 18:31    1   CI-99   1   403-26  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.
```

I tried to do it with:

```
sep = "<?xml"
result = text.split(sep, 1)[-1]
```

But the result cuts away my delimiter.
The resulting text.

```
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.
```

Any suggestions of how to avoid that so that the final result looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer some ways below:

## 1. Just concate seperator with split result

```
In [2]: text
Out[2]: '21.12.2017 18:31    1   CI-99   1   403-26  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.\n'

In [3]: sep = "<?xml"

In [4]: result = sep + text.split(sep, 1)[-1]

In [5]: result
Out[5]: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.\n'
```

## 2. get index an print rest of content

```
In [8]: text[text.index(sep):]
Out[8]: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.\n'
```

## 3. Using regex

```
In [9]: import re
In [10]: re.sub(r'(.*)<?xml', r'<?xml', text)
Out[10]: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.\n'
```

Comment: Thank you too for the hard work and for giving a few possibilities.

Comment: If it helps you, you can upvote and/or accept as answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use `split` for this.  Just find the substring, then use the result to index into the string:

```
s = "21.12.2017 18:31    1   CI-99   1   403-26  <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soapenv:Env ..."
r = s[s.index("<?xml"):]
```

Comment: WOW thank you very much i thought it would be more difficult. Thany you all who wrote me i will document the answers

Comment: BTW is there something like a Closed button for the topic ? My answer is perfectly  answered. Even more i can even choose.

Comment: @Computer85 You can "accept" the anwer that best resolves your problem.

Comment: Can i accept more than one answer ? Because there are some that are great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
We will add custom unique delimiter with our usual delimiter, and then split with this custom delimiter in this case `$`, keeping our original delimiter intact.

```
text = '21.12.2017 18:31    1   CI-99   1   403-26  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.'
result = text.replace("<?xml", "<?xml$").split('$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just search for your sep in text with `index` method:

```
sep = '<?xml'
result = text[text.index(sep):]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do this using regex:

```py
sep = "\<\?xml" #escape the special characters
pattern = re.compile(rf"({sep})+")

# I created a longer string to allow for multiple matches
text = text*3
raw_result = re.split(pattern, text) 

# If your delimiter is the end of the match group, start index = 0
# If your delimiter is the start of the match group, start index = 1
start_index = 1
result = ["".join([x,y]) for x,y in zip(
    raw_result[start_index::2], raw_result[start_index+1::2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append it before the result of split e.g.

```
text = '21.12.2017 18:31    1   CI-99   1   403-26  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.'
sep = "<?xml"
result = sep + text.split(sep, 1)[-1]
print(result)
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.
```

Comment: WOW thank you very much i thought it would be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a particular requirement to split the string and use regex then I would perform simple string manipulation. Find where `?xml` begins and get the characters to the left of this position:

```
str = "21.12.2017 18:31    1   CI-99   1   403-26  <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc."

ind = str.index("?xml")
print(ind)
print(str[0:ind - 1])


45
21.12.2017 18:31    1   CI-99   1   403-26
```

Answer (score 0):

unless you have use `split` for some reason you can find the `index` of `<?xml` and start the `string` from there:

```
text = '21.12.2017 18:31    1   CI-99   1   403-26  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.'
index = text.index('<?xml')
text = text[index:]
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

i can think of 2 ways to keep the`<?xml` after the split:

add sep to the start of the string manually

```
sep = "<?xml"
result = sep + text.split(sep, 1)[-1]
```

or maybe a more elegant solution would be to find the `<?xml` and slice the string just before it (assuming you know that it is actually there)

```
sep = "<?xml"
index = text.find(sep)
result = text[index:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the start of `'<?xml'` with [str.find()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), then slice the string at this index:

```
>>> text = '21.12.2017 18:31    1   CI-99   1   403-26  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.'
>>> text[text.find('<?xml'):]
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Env etc. etc.'
```